# I can't seem to get my Chakra form to dynamically render inputs

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am building an app with a login page (LoginPage) with a login & sign-up form (Form) and a function that renders fields dynamically (formActions). When I use the console to debug, it seems that the fieldVal.type isn't 'File'??? Can anyone help point me in the right direction as to why it keeps rendering as a string input?

Login Page:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Box, Tabs, TabList, TabPanels, Tab, TabPanel } from '@chakra-ui/react'

import Form from '../components/Form';

export default function LoginPage() {
    const [loginCredentials, setLoginCredentials] = useState({
        username: {
          type: String,
          value: '',
        },
        password: {
          type: String,
          value: '',
        },
      })
    
    const [signupCredentials, setSignupCredentials] = useState({
        email: {
          type: String,
          value: '',
        },
        username: {
          type: String,
          value: '',
        },
        password: {
          type: String,
          value: '',
        },
        passwordConfirm: {
          type: String,
          value: '',
        },
        profilePic: {
          type: File,
          value: '',
        },
      })

    return (
        <Box>
            <Tabs>
                <TabList>
                    <Tab>Login</Tab>
                    <Tab>SignUp</Tab>
                </TabList>

                <TabPanels>
                    <TabPanel>
                        <Form formName={'Login'}
                            formFields={loginCredentials} 
                            setPropsState={setLoginCredentials}/>
                    </TabPanel>
                    <TabPanel>
                        <Form formName={'Sign Up'}
                            formFields={signupCredentials} 
                            setPropsState={setSignupCredentials}/>
                    </TabPanel>
                </TabPanels>
            </Tabs>
        </Box>

    );
}
```

Form:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FormControl, Button } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { renderFields } from '../utils/formActions'

export default function Form(props) {
    const formFields = props.formFields

    const handleChange = (field, value) => {
        const updatedFields = { ...formFields };
        updatedFields[field].value = value;
        props.setPropsState(updatedFields);
        console.log(formFields)
    }

    return (
        <FormControl>
            {renderFields(formFields, handleChange)}
            <Button>{props.formName}</Button>
        </FormControl>
    )
}
```

formActions:

```
import { Input } from '@chakra-ui/react'

function renderFields(e, handleChange) {
    // return KVPs as an array
    const fieldsArr = Object.entries(e);
    // for each index in the array, create a field
    return fieldsArr.map(([fieldName, fieldVal]) => {
        if (fieldVal.type === 'File') {
            console.log('FILE FILE FILE')
            console.log(fieldVal.type)
            return (
                <input key={fieldName}
                    type='file'
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(fieldName, e.target.files[0])}/>
            );
        } else {
            console.log(fieldVal.type)
            return (
                <Input key={fieldName}
                    placeholder={fieldName}
                    value={fieldVal.value}
                    type="string"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(fieldName, e.target.value)} />
            );
        }
    });
}

export {
    renderFields,
}
```